# retain form values onclick after javascript validation fails

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, validation

This is part of an assignment.  Everything that's supposed to work, already works, but there's something that bothers me.  The only purpose of the code so far is to test our ability to validate from data.  Anyway, right now the validate() function is attached to a submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Find Love" onclick="validate()">
```

When any validation fails, all the text boxes, drop downs, etc. are cleared, but I want them to retain their values and just focus on the first incorrect value (retaining their values is more important to me at this point).  The actual   Does that require some modification of the onclick function or a different function all together?  Please help.  If you need to see the javascript I can post that as well.

```
function validate()
{
var blnValid = true;

if(isBlank("txtFName"))
{
    blnValid = false;
    alert("First name cannot be blank!")
    document.getElementById("txtFName").focus();
}

if(blnValid)
{   
    if(isBlank("txtLName"))
    {
        blnValid = false;
        alert("Last name cannot be blank!")
        document.getElementById("txtLName").focus();
    }
}
if(blnValid)
{
    if(isBlank("txtAge"))
    {
        blnValid = false;
        alert("Age cannot be blank!")
        document.getElementById("txtAge").focus();
    }
}
if(blnValid)
{
    var strInput = document.getElementById("txtAge").value;
    if(!isInt(strInput))
    {
        blnValid = false;
        alert("You must enter a valid number in the age field.")
        document.getElementById("txtAge").select();
    }
}
if(blnValid)
{
    if(document.getElementById("selUserGender").selectedIndex <= 0)
    {
        alert("Please select your gender");
        blnValid = false;
    }
}
if(blnValid)
{
    if(document.getElementById("selFindGender").selectedIndex <= 0)
    {
        alert("Please select your gender");
        blnValid = false;
    }
}
if(blnValid)
{
    blnChecked = false;
    arRadio = document.forms[0].rdbAgeRange;
    for (var i = 0; i < arRadio.length; i++)
    {
        if(arRadio[i].checked)
        {
            blnChecked = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!blnChecked)
    {
        alert("You must select an age group.");
        blnValid = false;
    }
}
if(blnValid)
{
    if(!document.getElementById("chkSkeeball").checked
        && !document.getElementById("chkAir").checked
        && !document.getElementById("chkCliff").checked
        && !document.getElementById("chkHamster").checked)
    {
        blnValid = false;
        alert("You must select a hobby.")
    }   
}

return blnValid;
}


function isInt(strValue)
{
var validNums = "0123456789";
var blnIsNumber = true;
var tempChar;

for (var i = 0; i < validNums.length; i++)
{
    tempChar = strValue.substr(i, 1);
    if (validNums.indexOf(tempChar) == -1)
    {
        return false;

    }
}
return true;
}

function isBlank(elementID)
{
if(document.getElementById(elementID).value.length == 0)
{
    return true;
}

return false;
}
```

Comment: Please do. Probably there is a line there that clears the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is actually your HTML. Nothing in your Javascript is going to clear the elements but because you're using onClick the form is actually submitting anyway. I assume that it probably just submits back to the page and clears everything. Instead of onClick use onSubmit in the form element:

```
<form method="post" action="url_of_action" onSubmit="return validate()">
```

If it's not valid it will prevent the form from submitting.

Comment: Sorry,this is my first post to this site. I can't seem to work the comment box...  I changed the markup to what you suggested, but the same thing happened

Comment: do you get the alert boxes at all?

Comment: You know, I just tried it again (I haven't looked at it since yesterday), and it works.  Thanks!  Now I just need to research that action value.

Comment: I can't vote your answer up, my rep isn't high enough, or something.  Also, is there an easy way to embed code in these comment boxes?

Comment: The action value should point to a URL that processes your form. (Usually a file written in a server side language like PHP). If the object of your lesson is the Javascript it's ok to leave it blank.

Comment: You should be able to edit your answer. As for my answer click the checkbox to accept it. That's better than voting it up :-D

Answer (score 0):

Missing semi-colons:

```
if(isBlank("txtFName"))
{
    blnValid = false;
    alert("First name cannot be blank!") //here
    document.getElementById("txtFName").focus();
}

if(blnValid)
{   
    if(isBlank("txtLName"))
    {
        blnValid = false;
        alert("Last name cannot be blank!") //and here
        document.getElementById("txtLName").focus();
    }
}
if(blnValid)
{
    if(isBlank("txtAge"))
    {
        blnValid = false;
        alert("Age cannot be blank!") //and here
        document.getElementById("txtAge").focus();
    }
}
```